# If "Presenter" is setting a Property on the "View" is it a violation of MVP Pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, unit-testing, mvp

I am new to MVP and trying to get the picture.

And I am stucked at one point:

In order to be able to unit-test more on my View, I would like to also shift some property settings to PRESENTER. So that I can see if some View properties are set and also set properly.

But at this point my 6th sense is whispering me quite noisy that I started to doubt if I am breaking MVP pattern by doing this. Because it sounds like "setting" more than "presenting" to me :(

So, if "Presenter" is setting a Property on the "View" is it a violation of MVP Pattern?

Thanks

Comment: See my previous answer that somewhat covers your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794121/model-view-presenter-in-winforms/4818268#4818268

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MVP the Presenter is *supposed* to set properties on the View.  You may be thinking of MVC where the Controller is simply responsible for handing the View a reference to the Model.  In MVP the Presenter is typically pretty tightly tied to the View and responsible for directly setting properites.

Comment: Just the term 'Presenter' was a bit misleading me as it sounds like Prsenter should 'present' Not manage or manipulate... At least this is how I imagined after hearing the term PRESENTER.