# Building C# GUI without using Visual Studio GUI designer (Toolbox)

Tags: c#, eclipse, swing, visual-studio, netbeans

In Java Swing, we can create GUI with only coding Java (for example in Eclipse). Using NetBeans's toolbox to drag and drop components to the UI is optional.

I am wondering if there is the same concept in C#. Can I put my components into my GUI and add them behaviors with only coding? That way I would feel that I have more control over my application.

Example: I do not want to g to toolbox to add "mousehover" to my button! Instead, I want to write the code myself. I know where I can find the code, but is it the only place that I should write that line of code?

Please compare Java Swing with C# in this.

Comment: What if I give you a small explanation of how to write C# code in a `Text Editor` and then tell you how to run it on a `cmd.exe` ? Will that do, the whole procedure (step by step), without using `Visual Studio` anywhere ... :-)

Comment: This did not answer my question, but thanks for your comment. In fact, I am interested to learn that as well. Please let me know how to do so.

Comment: Please see the answer, does this answers a bit regarding your question :-)

Answer (score 13):

### Regarding C# :

In order for you to run a `C#` application from a `cmd`, following steps are needed :

1. Go to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` location on your File System and copy the path.
2. Now right click `Computer` go to Properties.
3. Under `System Properties`, select `Advanced` Tab, and click on `Environment Variables`.
4. On `Environment Variables` under `User Variables`, select `New`.
5. For `Variable Name` write `CSHARP_HOME` or something else, though I am using the same for further needs to explain this out. For `Variable Value` simply `Paste` what you copied in **Step 1**. Click OK.
6. Again perform **Step 4**, if `path` variable does not exist, else you can simply select `path` and then click `Edit` to perform this next thingy (after putting **;(semi-colon)** at the end of the `Variable Value` and write `%CSHARP_HOME%\`(or use what you used in **Step 5**) ). This time for `Variable Name` write `path`, and for `Variable Value` use `%CSHARP_HOME%\` and click OK.
7. Open `cmd` and type `csc` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, you might be able to see something like this as an output
   [image: CMD OUTPUT 1]
8. Now consider I am creating a directory structure for my CSharp Project like this (on File System) at this location `C:\Mine\csharp\command`. Here I created two folders inside `command` folder. **source** and **build**.
9. Now from any `Text Editor` create a small sample program (I am using Notepad++), as below, save it as `WinFormExample.cs` under `source` folder :

---

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CSharpGUI {
    public class WinFormExample : Form {

        private Button button;

        public WinFormExample() {
            DisplayGUI();
        }

        private void DisplayGUI() {
            this.Name = "WinForm Example";
            this.Text = "WinForm Example";
            this.Size = new Size(150, 150);
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            button = new Button();
            button.Name = "button";
            button.Text = "Click Me!";
            button.Size = new Size(this.Width - 50, this.Height - 100);
            button.Location = new Point(
                (this.Width - button.Width) / 3 ,
                (this.Height - button.Height) / 3);
            button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.MyButtonClick);

            this.Controls.Add(button);
        }

        private void MyButtonClick(object source, EventArgs e) {
            MessageBox.Show("My First WinForm Application");
        }

        public static void Main(String[] args) {
            Application.Run(new WinFormExample());
        }
    }
}
```

---

10. Now type `csc /out:build\WinFormExample.exe source\WinFormExample.cs` (more info is given at the end, for compiler options)and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to compile as shown below :
    [image: CMD OUTPUT 2]
11. Now simply run it using `.\build\WinExample`, as shown below :
    [image: CMD OUTPUT 3]
12. Now your simple `GUI Application` is up and running :-)

Do let me know, I can explain the same thingy regarding `Java` as well, if need be :-)

More info regarding `Compiler Options` can be found on [C# Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @mahshidzeinaly : Though you can use the above code in your Visual Studio projects too, simply go to `Form1.Designer.cs` file and add all using statements on top, the three as presented in the example code by me, simply call `displayGUI()` from within `InitializeComponent()` method

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing magic in WinForms drag & drop.  You can reference the same classes from System.Windows.Forms.  If you are going to roll your own, I would suggest looking at the [Model View Presenter pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794121/model-view-presenter-in-winforms).

Here is a [nice article](http://swinbrain.ict.swin.edu.au/wiki/Windows_Forms_vs._Swing) comparing Java Swing and WinForms: