# How to hide a button on form using button on another form

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm using a MDIparent form having two panels. panel1 contains form1 and panel2 contains form2. I want to hide buttons on form1 on clicking button on form2. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

short description:

```
        => your A - form needs a click event "button_clicked"
        => MDI Parent recognize the event ( use a delegate / Listener )
        => MDI Parent has a list of his childforms
        => your B - form needs a public function "hide_button" who hides your control
        => check if your B - form is open
        => loop to the desired childform and call the function
```

for a more detailled answer, post a code example :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite difficult to help without an example, but let's try...

As we can see, you're working with two fixed Panels at your MDI Form, right?
I will not assume that you're using some kind of pattern, but you should. Please, take a look at:

- [Model-View-Presenter in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794121/model-view-presenter-in-winforms)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522809/WinForms-MVP-An-MVP-Framework-for-Winforms

So, without a pattern, I think the most easy way to achieve that is by DataBindings.

You should first create a class that contains everything you want to control, like the Enabled property from your Buttons. You must use the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) pattern to make the DataBinding, so, your controller may look like this:

```
internal class Controller : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool button1Enabled;

    public bool Button1Enabled
    {
        get { return this.button1Enabled; }
        set
        {
            if (this.button1Enabled == value) return;
            this.button1Enabled = value;
            this.NotifyChange("Button1Enabled");
        }
    }
}
```

Your MDI Form should have:

```
internal partial class MDIParent1 : Form
{
    private IControllerChanged controller;

    public MDIParent1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.controller = new Controller();
    }
}
```

The form that contains the button may have:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button1st.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", this.controller, "Button1Enabled", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

And the Form that will control the Button may have:

```
private void button3rd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.controller.Button1Enabled = !this.controller.Button1Enabled;
}
```

With this idea, you can control everything on your fixed Forms.

Using this example, I made a very, very simple program, trying to figure out your necessity. Please, take a look at https://github.com/anderson-rancan/stackoverflow_32189531