Implementation of MVP using the WinForms platform
I am creating an application on WinForms using the MVP pattern. I have a separate project for each form, the interfaces for the views are in a separate project. The presenters also have their own separate project. I had two questions:

How to properly structure a Winforms application using MVP

How, if necessary, to add a control to the form through the presenter (I have a main form and there is a registration button on it, clicking on this button opens the registration form as a registration form I use UserControl).


I created a presenter in the winforms class library, used the Action delegate as an event parameter, but I think this is not the right approach and there is a better solution

https://github.com/DavidRogersDev/WinformsMVP

these resources might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794121/model-view-presenter-in-winforms

Your Form class is the Presenter: it is between the View (= interaction with the operator) and your Model.
I assume you know how to use Visual Studio Designer to create and design your form.
Your Form class has (a reference to) an instance to your Model.
IMyModel Model {get => ...}

Input from Operator (View) to the Model
Whenever the operator presses a button, selects a item, etc, an event is generated. Use Visual Studio designer to generate an event handler for this. This event handler is created in your Form class (Presenter).
For example, the operator types a Product ID in a TextBox, then presses the button "Get Product Information". In your form class:
void OnButtonGetProductInformation_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.DisplayRequestedProduct();
}

The event handler is very small. This enables you to reuse DisplayRequestedProduct, for instance after selection of a menu item in event handler OnMenuItemFetchProduct_Clicked(). If later you don't want to wait until the operator presses a button, but want to display the requested product as soon as he presses , the changes are minimal.
void DisplayRequestedProduct()
{
    string textProductId = this.textBoxProductId.Text;
    int productId = Int32.Parse(textProductId)
    this.DisplayProduct(productId);
}

void DisplayProduct(int productId)
{
    IProduct product = this.Model.GetProduct(productId)
    // fetches the product with productId from the Database

    this.DisplayProduct(product);
}


Product DisplayedProduct {get; set;}

void DisplayProduct(Product product)
{
    // show some product data in labels
    this.labelProductId.Text = product.Id;
    this.labelProductName.Text = product.Name;
    this.labelProductDescription.Text = product.Description;
    this.labelProductPrice.Text = product.Price.ToString(...);
    this.labelProductStock.Text = product.Stock.ToString(...);

    this.DisplayedProduct = product;
}

I separated the action into small methods, so the methods are easier to unit test, can be reused, and changes won't affect other methods. For instance if you want to show the fetched product in edit boxes, or in a table, the other procedures won't change.
By the way, for simplicity I didn't check the input productId. Of course you should check if the input is a proper integer, and if the input is productId of an existing product.
Output from Model to View
Some models have data that changes. The changes should be updated automatically in the view. For example if a Product has been sold, then the Stock should be updated, and if the Product has been sold out, then the displayed products should be displayed in red.
IMyModel should raise an event whenever one of the product changes. In your form you should subscribe to this event:
void SubScribeEventProductChanges()
{
    this.Model.ProductChanged += this.OnProductChanged;
}

void OnProductChanged(object sender, ProductChangedEventData e)
{
    // is my displayed Product changed?
    if (e.ChangedProduct.Id == this.DisplayedProduct.Id
    {
        // The name, price, etc of the Product can be changed 
        this.DisplayProduct(e.ChangedProduct);  // slightly changed version
    }
    // else: not my product, nothing to do
}

void DisplayProduct(Product product)
{
    Color productTextColor = this.GetProductTextColor(product);
    this.SetProductDisplayColor(productTextColor);

    // as in earlier method:
    this.labelProductId.Text = product.Id;
    this.labelProductName.Text = product.Name;
    ...
}

Color GetProductTextColor(Product product)
{
    return (product.Stock == 0) ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
}

void SetProductDisplayColor(Color productDisplayColor)
{
    this.labelProductId.ForeColor = productDisplayColor;
    this.labelProductName.ForeColor = productDisplayColor;
    ... etc.
}

Because I made small procedures that have only one small task, the changes I had to make to existing procedures are minimal.
Conclusion
To implement MVP, or MVVM:
The model should raise events whenever values that others need to know change.
The form class must have a property that returns the interface to the model object. Input from operator is handled by the form class using events. If that means that the model must be notified, the form class class methods from the model interface.
The form class subscribes to the model events that it needs. If the event is raised, the model class checks if the View must be updated, and acts accordingly.
Finally: if you think that a lot of your Presenter procedures might be reused in another Form, consider to put those methods (like DisplayRequestedProduct) in a separate Presenter class:

If several forms should use the same Model, then the Model is created by the Application. If the Model is unique for your form, then the Form creates the Model
Similarly, if several independent Forms should use the same Presenter, then the Presenter object is created by the Application. If your form uses its own Presenter, then the Presenter is created by the Form.
You form contains the event handlers, and has a reference to the Presenter object. The Presenter holds a reference to the Model

